# A new view is not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just made a view using CGRectMake but the view is not visible. Here's my code until now:

```
mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,320,460)];
    mainView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    mainView.alpha = 1.0;
    [mainView setHidden:NO];
```

Is there another property I need to add in order to make it be visible/functional?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add view on main view. So do like below.

```
[self.view addSubview:mainView];
```

So Just replace whole code with below.

```
mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,320,460)];
mainView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
mainView.alpha = 1.0;
[mainView setHidden:NO];
[self.view addSubview:mainView];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the new view to an existing view. You could use (for example):

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myNewView];
```

If you are using a `UIViewController`, it would be:

```
[[myViewController view] addSubview:myNewView];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it as a subview in your UIViewController or you UIApplication keyWindow.

Also, you have to make sure its frame position is inside the parentView application bounds **IF** the parent view has the `clipToBounds` property set to `YES`